# How do I make a CSS element scroll with the page if it is already absolutely positioned?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have implemented a slide in/out form with a tab to activate this functionality. It works just as I want it except that the tab always stays in the same position because it is absolutely positioned with CSS. I want it to be position where it is but to scroll with the page.

Here is the CSS

```
#slidingform-slider {
width: 500px;
top: 100px;
position: absolute;
}

#slidingform-sidebar1 {
position: absolute !important;
top: 180px !important;
left: 113px !important;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px gray;
z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

and here is the html

```
<div id="slidingform-sidebar1" onclick="slidingform_close_panel()">
<button class="contact-slideout-toggle contact-slideout-btn btn btn-lg         btn-primary hidden-xs hidden-sm">Request a Call Back</button>
</div>
<div id="slidingform-header">   
<--- form in here --->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just put a wrapper round the whole thing and gave it the following css:

```
.slider-wrap {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
z-index: 10000;
}
```